# Close InitialContext

Tags: java, initial-context

I have a class that uses a method from another `EJBHelper` class which calls the method `getInitialContext` to initialize an `InitialContext`.

Now, the problem is that I need to close the `InitialContext` after the EJB process ends.
Please help; how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you don't need to close the InitialContext.

Comment: Hey,Thanks for reply.I Need to close as it giving some waiting error when using with Jboss server.

Comment: InitialContext is used for EJB lookup. So once you get the reference to your EJB it should be possible to close it. If this does not work please post the error you get from JBoss.